# 'My tags' tab in 'questions'

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting

The Unanswered tab can be sorted by 'my tags', which is very useful. I'd love to have that option in the Questions tab.

I know I can search for a tag, e.g. [lord-of-the-rings], and my tags are highlighted, but I still have to go through lots of questions that don't interest me at all.

Comment: This has been requested a long time ago: [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags) I'm afraid the request was declined.

Comment: @Gilles Why was it declined?

Comment: Jeff Atwood posted an answer (now deleted) when he declined the request: “We believe that browsing by tag, and tag combination, should be sufficient. The bleedthrough and forced exposure to other topics is intentional; we believe programmers have more in common across languages and disciplines than they think they do. We don't want to create more "ghettos" where programmers only care about or look at certain pet topics. Good programmers are well-rounded, and are aware of the world outside their "special preferred" tag.” It may be worth revisiting (especially on non-SO sites).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply in the search box, type your favorite tags, separated by "OR". Like this:

> [lord-of-the-rings] OR [star-wars] OR [halo]

If you want to make this a feature request, you'd be better off checking [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).